# Sending a value from a form created using PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a gym website and I have a **table** with all the available classes names which I retrieved from a dataset, next to each class there are two options, Enroll and Drop.
Clicking ‘drop’ or ‘enroll’ will trigger an AJAX request to the appropriate PHP page. When the PHP page responds successfully, the trainee home page should update the interface accordingly.
So my problem is, clicking enroll will only work if the class was based on the first row of the table, else the page will only refresh
which i assume is the AJAX request only receives the first row's value.

here is my Trainee homepage, where i did my table:

```
<table class="content-table" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 12%">
                <caption style="font-size:20px; font-weight: bold; color: white;">Available Fitness Classes<br><br></caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th colspan="3"><p id='xx1' style="color: Red"></p></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Class WHERE CL_id IN (SELECT class_id FROM Enrolment Where trainee_id ='".$_SESSION['T_id']."');";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                  
                    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                          $id= $row1['CL_id'];
                        echo "<tr>
                              <td><a href='InfoPage.php?CL_id=".$id."'>{$row1['name']}</a></td>
                              <td>Enrolled</td>
                              <td><form method='post' id='formtwo'>
                              <input  id='try2' type='hidden' name='Drop' value='{$row1['name']}'/> 
                                <button id='btwo' onclick='functwo(); return false;' style='border:none; background-color:transparent; font-size:100%;'>Drop</button>
                              </form></td>
                              
                              </tr>";
                    }
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Class WHERE CL_id NOT IN (SELECT class_id FROM Enrolment Where trainee_id ='".$_SESSION['T_id']."');";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                        $id= $row2['CL_id'];
                        echo "<tr>
                              <td><a href='InfoPage.php?CL_id=".$id."'>{$row2['name']}</a></td>
                              <td colspan=2>
                                <form method='post' id='formone'>
                                <input id='try1' type='hidden' name='Enroll' value='{$row2['name']}'/> 
                                <button id='bone' onclick='funcone({$row2['name']}); return false;' style='border:none; background-color:transparent; font-size:100%;'>Enroll</button>
                              </form></td>
                              
                              </tr>";
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <script>
        $("#bone").click(function funcone(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("TraineeEnroll.php",
                       { Enroll: $("#try1").val()},
                       function(data){
                            $("#xx1").html("Class was added successfully");
                        });
        });
        
        $("#btwo").click(function functwo(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("TraineeDrop.php",
                       { Drop: $("#try2").val()},
                       function(data){
                            $("#xx1").html("Class was dropped successfully");
                        });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my TraineeEnroll.PHP

```
<?php
session_start(); 
    include 'includes/connect.php';

$sql3 = "SELECT CL_id FROM Class WHERE name ='{$_POST['Enroll']}'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

$sql4 = "INSERT INTO Enrolment VALUES (".rand(1,99).",{$_SESSION['T_id']},{$row3['CL_id']});";
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);

echo"done";

?>
```

And my TraineeDrop.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
 include 'includes/connect.php';
 
$sql3 = "SELECT CL_id FROM Class WHERE name ='{$_POST['Drop']}'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

$sql = "DELETE FROM Enrolment WHERE trainee_id = '{$_SESSION['T_id']}' AND class_id = '{$row3['CL_id']}';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: TraineesPage.php");
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Anyway your problem is that you have forgotten that IDs in HTML must be unique. `<button id='bone'` gets created multiple times in your page because of your `while` loop. But an ID must only represent one single item...therefore `$("#bone").click` only ever selects the first one, and ignores the rest - for one thing it considers them invalid, and for another, how would it tell them apart, if they all have the same ID? It makes no sense. Give the buttons a class instead e.g. `class="bone"` and then use jQuery to select any buttons with that class to attach the click to e.g. `$(".bone").click`.

Comment: You're going to have a similar issue with `$("#try1").val()` ...instead you need give these classes as well, and then select the copy of that which is closest to the click button - or perhaps the one which has a common parent element. JQuery has functions for doing either of those things, so I'll let you do a bit of research on how to sort that bit out - it's not a new problem, plenty of people have done it before, so it should be a very easy topic to look into.